# Parsing an expression containing repeated groups using Java regexp

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse from a string like below

"`name1(value1),name2(value2),name3(value3),name4(value4),........`" and so it goes

How can I do it recursively with groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "name1(value1),name2(value2),name3(value3),name4(value4),";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would rather use the java String operations to get to the values but if you want to use regex, you could use something that looks like that:

```
[^\(]*\([^\)]*\),
```

Should be quite stable

You can test it here:
http://regexr.com?2u7u3

Comment: +1 for [^(] and [^)]. I'd give you another one for "String operations" if I could :).

Comment: I have a static final Pattern in the class, so I'm not creating the pattern object each time. Do you still think regex operation will be much costlier than String ops?

Comment: yes i do think so, the string ops are easy to handle and are designed efficient; i am not 100% sure if String ops are more efficient, but the difference wound be noticeable; i just think that string operations are a much cleaner way to perform this task

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matcher.find`, try something like this:

```
String input = "name1(value1),name2(value2),name3(value3),name4(value4)";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*?[(].*?[)]").matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

or just use `String.split` like this:

```
String input = "name1(value1),name2(value2),name3(value3),name4(value4)";
String[] split = input.split(",");
```